# EitherT with multiple return types

Tags: scala, scala-cats, for-comprehension

I am trying to compose futures with for-comprehension and EitherT, but I am having trouble due the return types. Please can someone explain why this does not compile and how can I make it compile changing the for-comprehension?

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

import cats.data.EitherT
import cats.implicits._

object CatsApp extends App {

  case class L1(a: String)
  case class L2(a: String)
  case class L3(a: String)

  case class R1(num: Int)
  case class R2(num: Int)
  case class R3(num: Int)

  def func1: Future[Either[L1, R1]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R1(1)))
    else Future(Left(L1("A")))
  }

  def func2: Future[Either[L2, R2]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R2(1)))
    else Future(Left(L2("A")))
  }

  def func3(a: R1, b: R2): Future[Either[L3, R3]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R3(a.num + b.num)))
    else Future(Left(L3("A")))
  }

  def comp = {
    for {
      f1 <- EitherT(func1)
      f2 <- EitherT(func2)
      f3 <- EitherT(func3(f1, f2))
    } yield f3
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a for-comprehension the type and the bias of the **first** step in the chain determines the type of all the rest of the steps in the chain have to be. Because `Either` is right-biased, we can only change the right type between the steps of the for-comprehension, as advised by @Krzysztof. For example,

```
val e1: Either[String, Int] = Right(42)
val e2: Either[String, Char] = Right('A')

for {
  num  <- e1
  char <- e2
} yield "I compile despite having different Rights"
```

In your case the type of first step `EitherT(func1)` is `EitherT[Future, L1, R1]`, hence the next steps  `EitherT(func2)` and `EitherT(func3(f1, f2))` must have the following shape of the type

```
EitherT[Future, L1, X]
```

where only `X` can vary. One way to make your for-comprehension happy is to create **algebraic data types** out of `L`s  like so

```
  sealed abstract class L(val a: String)
  final case class L1(s: String) extends L(s)
  final case class L2(s: String) extends L(s)
  final case class L3(s: String) extends L(s)
```

Here is a working [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/rxX2h1f4SsWJ7fD0VA2OQg)

```
object CatsApp extends App {

  sealed abstract class L(val a: String)
  final case class L1(s: String) extends L(s)
  final case class L2(s: String) extends L(s)
  final case class L3(s: String) extends L(s)

  case class R1(num: Int)
  case class R2(num: Int)
  case class R3(num: Int)

  def func1: Future[Either[L, R1]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R1(1)))
    else Future(Left(L1("A")))
  }

  def func2: Future[Either[L, R2]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R2(1)))
    else Future(Left(L2("A")))
  }

  def func3(a: R1, b: R2): Future[Either[L, R3]] = {
    if (true) Future(Right(R3(a.num + b.num)))
    else Future(Left(L3("A")))
  }

  def comp: EitherT[Future, L, R3] = {
    for {
      f1 <- EitherT(func1)
      f2 <- EitherT(func2)
      f3 <- EitherT(func3(f1, f2))
    } yield f3
  }

  comp.value.andThen(v => println(v))
}
```

which outputs

```
Success(Right(R3(2)))
```

Comment: Hi Mario, thanks for your answer. I've struggled with this topic in FP the most, both through learning Haskel and now with Scala. With Scala 3's support for basic non-tagged union types, I thought we could compose Eithers with different left types and have them automatically widen. But it seems that's not the case. What are you supposed to do if you have multiple types of errors in your application, e.g. domain errors and application errors (which could be themselves be declared as separate types, e.g. one kind of error type for each adapter). Hope you can shine some light on this!

Comment: Just to expand on the last comment, what I'm referring to in particular is a Hexagonal style arch. with ports and adapters. The thing that attracted me to FP is the IO/effect type and error handling, which means we can be super accurate when defining the ports compared to in a language like Python. It seems tragic that we are expected to have one set of errors across the entire application. This means the dependency inversion happily allows an adapter to return any possible error totally unrelated to the function of the adapter (e.g. an infra adapter being allowed to throw a domain error).