# Handling multiple error types via either/disjunction Scala

Tags: scala, error-handling, functional-programming, scalaz, either

I have 3 distinct modules each with its own error type. Following is a very simplified version.

```
object ModuleA {
  case class ErrorA(msg: String)
  def getA: ErrorA \/ String = "1".right
}

object ModuleB {
  case class ErrorB(msg: String)
  def getB(s: String): ErrorB \/ Int = 1.right
}

object ModuleC {
  case class ErrorC(msg: String)
  def getC(s: String, i: Int): ErrorC \/ Long = 1L.right
}
```

As a client of these modules what's the best way to chain these calls.

First - deeply nested, complex return type, but has all the types required.

```
def call1: ModuleA.ErrorA \/ (ModuleB.ErrorB \/ (ModuleC.ErrorC \/ Long)) = {
  ModuleA.getA.map { s =>
    ModuleB.getB(s).map { i =>
      ModuleC.getC(s, i)
    }
  }
}
```

Second - Very readable, but the error types are lost (Inferred return type is `Product \/ Long`). Ideally would want something similar with the error types

```
def call2  =
  for {
    s  <- ModuleA.getA
    i  <- ModuleB.getB(s)
    l  <- ModuleC.getC(s, i)
  } yield l
```

Third - Define new error types to encapsulate the existing ones. This seems unfeasible for different combinations

Lastly, tried to use EitherT, but seemed to get complex

Comment: Does '3 distinct modules' mean that your intent is to keep them encapsulated and unaware of each other? If so – where is the client supposed to be located? One of those three modules? The fourth one?

Comment: Yes, those could be 3 independent libraries. We would need one or more of those libraries in a client application. Example one of the lib deals with HDFS, one with Hive and the third with Configurations.

Answer (score 4):

Consider creating an algebraic data type out of the errors, for [example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/196LZwOQS8Sk3f47f3XqYQ)

```
sealed abstract class Error(val message: String)
case class ErrorA(msg: String) extends Error(msg)
case class ErrorB(msg: String) extends Error(msg)
case class ErrorC(msg: String) extends Error(msg)
```

and then change the left side of returned `\/` to `Error`

```
import scalaz.\/
import scalaz.syntax.either._

object ModuleA {
  def getA: Error \/ String = "1".right
}

object ModuleB {
  def getB(s: String): Error \/ Int = ErrorB("boom").left
}

object ModuleC {
  def getC(s: String, i: Int): Error \/ Long = 1L.right
}

for {
  s  <- ModuleA.getA
  i  <- ModuleB.getB(s)
  l  <- ModuleC.getC(s, i)
} yield l
```

which gives

```
res0: Error \/ Long = -\/(ErrorB(boom))
```

---

If you cannot create ADT, consider `leftMap` to change the error type to a common type like so

```
case class ErrorWrapper(m: String)

for {
  s  <- ModuleA.getA.leftMap { e: ModuleA.ErrorA => ErrorWrapper(e.msg) }
  i  <- ModuleB.getB(s).leftMap { e: ModuleB.ErrorB => ErrorWrapper(e.msg) }
  l  <- ModuleC.getC(s, i).leftMap { e: ModuleC.ErrorC => ErrorWrapper(e.msg) }
} yield l
// res0: ErrorWrapper \/ Long = -\/(ErrorWrapper(boom))
```

or maybe even, unusually, via structural typing

```
implicit class CommonErrorWrapper[A <: Product { def msg: String }](e: A) {
  def toErrorWrapper: ErrorWrapper = ErrorWrapper(e.msg)
}

for {
  s  <- ModuleA.getA.leftMap(_.toErrorWrapper)
  i  <- ModuleB.getB(s).leftMap(_.toErrorWrapper)
  l  <- ModuleC.getC(s, i).leftMap(_.toErrorWrapper)
} yield l
// res1: ErrorWrapper \/ Long = -\/(ErrorWrapper(boom))
```

`leftMap` is useful not only for changing the error type, but also we can enrich the error by adding locally available contextual information.

---

Note `EitherT` monad transformer may be used when the shape of type is `F[A \/ B]`, for example, `Future[Error \/ B]`, however in your case it is just `A \/ B`, hence `EitherT` is might not be the right tool. Related question [EitherT with multiple return types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59620066/eithert-with-multiple-return-types)

Comment: I've been looking at this question, and I like your solution (the most recent version with the implicit class). One thing to add, perhaps, is that one can also combine both things: ADT and the mapping, and map the module-level errors into the 'application-level errors' that are represented as a sealed trait hierarchy.

Comment: I guess there's no clean way to express this. Maybe with Dotty we could express as sum of error types. I haven't played around with Dotty so am not very sure
```
(ErrorA | ErrorB | Error C) \/ Long
```